# Codes block has an syntax error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, google-sheets

For some reason this code block is giving an error and i can't figure out what is the matter with it. Any help is appreciated.

```
function Submit(e) {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s     = e.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.getActiveRange();
  var cell  = range.getActiveCell();
  var cellValue  = ss.getActiveCell(9,17);

  if( cellValue == <0 ){
    var report = s.getDataRange("A101:Q106");
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
    var date = s.getSheetName();
    var target = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastColumn() + 1 , 1);
    e.getRange(report).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

Comment: You must be getting error `if( cellValue == <0 ){`. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: Use a code linter ...either in your IDE or an online one!!

Comment: You asked a question and got an answer. Please do not edit your question into a different question, since this invalidates the answer. Also, since the question is closed, people won't be able to answer your new question. It is much better to ask your new question in a new post.

Comment: It was the exact same code block but its completely overhauled since i figured out a lot more about how scripts work. The answer that was given was not the problem as i fixed that issue before it was even answered but it didn't fix the problem. However since i learned more about coding i cleaned up the code and simplified it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the line that is causing the syntax error:

```
if( cellValue == <0 ){
```

If you just want to know if `cellValue` is equal to 0, then you should change it to:

```
if( cellValue == 0 ){
```

If you're trying to see if `cellValue` is less than 0, then the proper way is:

```
if( cellValue < 0 ){
```

See http://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/comparison_operators for more information.

Comment: That's a valid option.  You're welcome to edit my answer if you want to add that.